# Inject mocked component into controller - integration testing - cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, integration-testing, cakephp-3.0

Currently, I'm writing an integration test for class which uses a component. Since this component uses third party services (in my case AWS S3) I want to replace the component with a mock component in order to avoid any communication with the third party service.

Part of controller class:

```
class AlbumsController extends AppController{
      public $components = ['Aws', 'Upload'];
      // Example of function that uses component
      public function add(){
            $album->pictures = $this->Aws->transformLinkIntoPresignedUrl($album->pictures);
      }
}
```

Part of integration test:

```
public function controllerSpy($event){
    parent::controllerSpy($event);
    if (isset($this->_controller)) {
        $this->_controller->Auth->setUser([
            'id' => $this->userId,
            'username' => 'testtesttesttest',
            'email' => 'john@doe.com',
            'first_name' => 'Mark',
            'last_name' => 'van der Laan',
            'uuid' => 'wepoewoweo-ew-ewewpoeopw',
            'sign_in_count' => 1,
            'current_sign_in_ip' => '127.0.0.1',
            'active' => true
        ]);
        // If the component is set, inject a mock
        if($this->_controller->Aws){
            $component = $this->getMock('App\Controller\Component\AwsComponent');
            $component->expects($this->once())
                ->method('transformLinkIntoPresignedUrl')
                ->will($this->returnValue(['link']));
            $this->_controller->Aws = $component;
        }
    }
}
```

Since this throws an error that transformLinkIntoPresignedUrl doesn't exist, I'm not sure if I'm on the right track for this particular problem. My question therefore is how can I inject mock/stub components into a controller and control its behavior (by setting fixed return values for the methods)?

Answer (score 0):

While I was looking at the code for IntegrationTestCase I found it impossible to do what you (and I) are trying to do. The best I could figure out is:

```
$this->controller = new AlbumsController();

$this->controller->Aws = $this->createMock(AwsComponent::class);
$this->controller->Aws
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('transformLinkIntoPresignedUrl');

$this->controller->add();
```

But it means you have to make mocks for Flash, Auth, request and other calls you take for granted because the Controller is just made in void. Here I'm reaching the limits of my Cake Knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this myself, and the determination I've currently reached is that it's not possible with an integration test. The creation of mocks will work if you're doing more of a unit test approach and testing your controller methods directly, but it doesn't appear to be able to get the request to have a controller instance that has anything mocked within it. Another approach that is slightly hacky, is to have some flag or method to indicate that you're in a test. Then in your actual controller code, you can verify that you're not in a test before calling the component.  I have used the tactic of setting an IS_PHPUNIT constant and checking for it being defined and having value. I'd say this isn't close to the best practice but can help at times when trying to bridge the gap between legacy/untested code and getting some testing to work.